# Salir de un bucle FOR en Java?

Tags: java, bucle-for

Estoy dentro de un ForEach, y para cada objeto hago ciertas comprobaciones. Lo que quiero es que si alguna comprobación falla, no se hagan las siguientes y se descarte ese objeto. En pseudocódigo sería algo así:

```
forEach (Objeto o : listaObjetos){
   o.comprobacion_uno();
   o.comprobacion_dos();
   o.comprobacion_tres();
   if (pasa_las_tres_comprobaciones) {
      listaObjetosValidos.add(o);
   }
}

// Si falla en la comprobacion_dos(), quiero que no se haga la tres y se pase directamente al siguiente objeto de listaObjetos. En caso de que pase las tres comprobaciones, se añade a una lista de objetos válidos.
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir también el código de los tres métodos para las comprobaciones (uno, dos y tres), por favor? ;D

Comment: Hola, ese código no es importante, son comprobaciones de formato. Si el objeto no cumple ciertas características de formato se descarta, pero ¿cómo hago para descartarlo?

Comment: Me refiero a que podrías hacer que guardaran cierto dato en una variable y luego rodear con un if a cada una de las comprobaciones, por eso me venía bien ver el código, para saber que es lo que haces y si devuelven algo o no, o almacenan algo en una variable... Quizás se puede utilizar lo que devuelven o guardan en una variable para validar si seguir comprobando o no. Es que sin eso no puedo darte una respuesta muy de acuerdo con lo que necesitas.

Comment: Estuve pensando en hacerlo mediante try-catch con excepciones controladas/creadas por mi pero no se si al capturar la excepción saldría completamente del foreach, o por el contrario pasaría al siguiente objeto.

Comment: Usar excepciones para controlar el flujo de ejecución no es una práctica recomendable, las excepciones se usan para controlar errores *excepcionales*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando `&&` para "corto-circuitar" las condiciones. Por ejemplo, dado:

```
 if (A && B) { ... }
```

Si A no se cumple, ya sabemos que A && B es falso valga lo que valga B, por lo que la condición B es ignorada. Por tanto tu código podría ser:

```
listaObjetos.forEach(objeto -> {
   boolean tresCondiciones = objeto.comprobacion_uno() &&
           objeto.comprobacion_dos() && objeto.comprobacion_tres();
   if (tresCondiciones) { ... }
});
```

Nota: estoy asumiendo que los métodos `comprobacion_n` devuelven un valor de tipo `boolean`

Pero si lo que quieres es crea una lista con los objetos que pasan las condiciones, podemos escribirlo así:

```
List<MiClase> listaFiltrada = listaObjetos.stream()
    .filter(objeto -> objeto.comprobacion_uno() &&
       objeto.comprobacion_dos() && objeto.comprobacion_tres())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Es decir, creamos una lista con los objetos que pasan el filtro, que es la función *lambda*

```
objeto -> objeto.comprobacion_uno() &&
       objeto.comprobacion_dos() && objeto.comprobacion_tres()
```

Si esta sintaxis te resulta extraña, es equivalente al método

```
boolean comprueba (MiClase objeto) {
    return objeto.comprobacion_uno() &&
        objeto.comprobacion_dos() && objeto.comprobacion_tres();
}
```

Comment: Entendido, lo hare con condicionales y no con excepciones. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @Pablo Lozano en su respuesta, lo más fácil es usar el operador &&

Este operador no evalúa las respuestas si ya no puede variar el resultado. En el caso del && cuando alguno de las pruebas es falsa el resultado será falso y no continúa. En el caso del || ocurriría lo mismo en el caso de que alguno fuera verdadero.

Adjunto un ejemplo sencillo de comprobación para que veas claramente el comportamiento de este operador. Cambia el valor devuelto por cada uno de las pruebas y verás el comportamiento de forma muy sencilla

```java
public class Prueba {
    private  static boolean comprobacion1() {
        System.out.println("comprobación 1");
        return true;
    }
    private static boolean comprobacion2() {
        System.out.println("comprobación 2");
        return false;
    }
    private static boolean comprobacion3() {
        System.out.println("comprobación 3");
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        boolean test = Prueba.comprobacion1() && Prueba.comprobacion2() && Prueba.comprobacion3();
        if (test){
            System.out.println("Ha pasado las comprobaciones");
        }
    }


}
```